# From float:left and right to under eachother

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am busy with my portfolio site and I am going to make it responsive.

The most things are responsive but i'm struggling with the [contact page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5AbJ.png).

Code:

```
.footerContact .informatie
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    color: white;
    width: 250px;
}

.footerContact .form
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    color: white;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Now i am using a media query to put them under each other when de screen size is smaller as 1115px

Example can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6TQX.png)

How can i do this?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1115px) 
{
    .footerContact .informatie
    {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 20%;
         margin-top: 10%;
         color: white;
        width: 250px;
    }   

    .footerContact .form
    {
        float: none;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-top: 100px;
        color: white;
        width: 250px;
    }

}
```

Comment: have you looked at [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is working properly in responsive mode.

You just have to set `margin: auto` to center align divs.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2mvewLo/1/

Answer (score 0):

Target all devices
    @media all and (max-width: 1115px) {

Then either set both to width: 100%; and float: left;

Or float: none; and margin: auto; (to center them).